# go casting interface{} to numbers

Tags: go

I'm playing around with go, but can't figure this out. here is a contrived example of what I want to do. Basically, i have number held in an `interface{}` data type and i want to write that binary representation of the number of a user specified size.

```
func main() {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)  // imported from encoding.binary 
   var val1 uint64 = 0xff    // 8 bytes
   var val2 float32 = 9.876  // 4 bytes

   var a interface{} = val1
   var b interface{} = val2

   // for argument sake, lets assume we want to write a as a uint8
   // to our binary file
   foo(buf.Bytes(), a, 1)

   // let's write b as a float64 to our binary file
   foo(buf,Bytes(), b, 8)

   // write buffer to file
   ...
}

// write the number in binary to the buffer
var foo (buf *bytes.Buffer, num interface{}, sizeInBytes int) {

   // TODO: somehow i need to convert num to the correct datatype
   //       let's assume the first scenario where num is unit64 and
   //       i need to make it uint8
   var tmp uint8 = num.(uint8) // error interface is uint64, not uint8
   var tmp uint8 = uint8(num)  // error (type interface {}) to type uint8: need type assertion

   // help please ^^^^^^ i assume writing a float32 as a float64 would
   // follow the same paradigm

    binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, num)
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you expect to get? `binary.Write` already takes an `interface{}` and asserts the correct type internally.

Comment: right, it does. but in my example, if i pass `a` (essentially a `uint64` it would write 0x00000000000000FF) however, i would like to have only 0xFF written to the file.

Comment: If the caller knows the size they want at call time, why not convert it in place rather than leaving `foo` to enumerate all possible combinations? (there's also the binary Varint encodings which use as little space as possible). Otherwise you end up with some copy&paste that looks like this: https://play.golang.org/p/koL6_PB3Ie and can't really be decoded without the original type and size combinations and order.

Comment: that has the same problem... the example just illustrates my problem. essentially, i get a `interface{}` given back to me after parsing json. i need to write it to the spec i'm following, but i need to know how many bytes to write given the data type in the spec. so converting it before calling `foo` or in `foo`, the same issue is presented where i need to convert `interface{}` to the "right" size in bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what, you're going to need to assert a concrete type for each value in order to operate on it numerically. Since converting smaller integer types is simply truncation, you could encode all integer values as `uint64` to reduce the number of cases you need to handle, then cut the slice at the desired number of bits.

```
func foo(buf *bytes.Buffer, num interface{}, sizeInBytes int) {
    switch sizeInBytes {
    case 1, 2, 4, 8:
        // OK
    default:
        panic("invalid size")
    }

    b := make([]byte, 8)
    var un uint64

    switch n := num.(type) {
    case float32:
        switch sizeInBytes {
        case 4:
            un = uint64(math.Float32bits(n))
        case 8:
            un = math.Float64bits(float64(n))
        default:
            panic("can't do that")
        }

    case float64:
        switch sizeInBytes {
        case 4:
            un = uint64(math.Float32bits(float32(n)))
        case 8:
            un = math.Float64bits(n)
        default:
            panic("can't do that")
        }
    case int8:
        un = uint64(n)
    case uint8:
        un = uint64(n)
    case uint16:
        un = uint64(n)
    case int16:
        un = uint64(n)
    case uint32:
        un = uint64(n)
    case int32:
        un = uint64(n)
    case uint64:
        un = uint64(n)
    case int64:
        un = uint64(n)
    case int:
        un = uint64(n)
    }

    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(b, un)
    b = b[:sizeInBytes]
    buf.Write(b)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g6d5Bt1esI